# washing machine starts draining immediately when turned on

Tags: washing-machine

Samtron wm-m640121 washing machine starts draining immediately when turned on and displays the error code (e33), no water in it and when adding water from the door before plugging it, it drains it after switching it on which means that the pump is working well.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If you can get the service manual, it will tell you the meaning of the error code; without that we won't be able to help. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: It's made in Russia, https://samtron.ru/goods/stiralnaya_mashina_samtron_wm_m640121/, so if you do find the manual you may need the help of a Russian speaker/translator